# How do you keep Hudson from giving Maven the -B option for builds?

Tags: java, maven-2, hudson, maven, andromda

When Hudson goes to build my project, it executes Maven as follows:

```
Executing Maven:  -B -f /path/to/root/pom.xml clean install
```

This works fine on most projects. (The -B is for "batch" or "non-interactive mode", BTW).

But for this one project that uses [AndroMDA](http://www.andromda.org/index.php) (which I can't recommend for future projects, it's really a pain-in-the-butt; slows down the build by 1000% with code generation for things that could be trivially done with inheritance and annotation-based config).

For some reason unbeknown to me, when Maven is given the -B flag the generated classes are no put on the classpath causing compilation errors for references to the generated classes. I've tested building manually with -B and without it and the result is that it builds fine without -B (outside of Hudson) and it doesn't build with -B (again, outside of Hudson).

Using Hudson version 1.369 and an external Maven 2.2.1 install.

Any advice greatly appreciated!!!

P.S. Hudson is AWESOME!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest version would be to have a free style project, and call maven yourself.